# The problem of not getting into Nova after uploading it to the server

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-nova

I have uploaded Nova on my server, but the problem is that when I press the login button, it does not work and this message appears
Summary URL: https://XXXXX/nova/login Status: 500 Internal Server Error Source: Network Address: 192.44.44.4.4:443 Initiator: xhr.js:187

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaWTy.png)

Comment: Could you add your laravel.log? There should be an error inside your log